# TWRP Not Flashing Correctly on Note 3 (SM-N9005)

Tags: samsung, twrp, odin, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I'm trying to install the TWRP Recovery on my Note 3 **SM-N9005** (which currently has stock ROM running Android 5.0) using **Odin v3.13**. I have downloaded the **TWRP 3.2.3 (hlte)** .tar from the official TWRP website and I have imported it on the AP section of Odin. Despite the fact that Odin says that everything went ok, when I'm going on the Recovery Menu, the stock recovery appears. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution by @beeshyams that worked in my case:

1. On Odin in the options tab; Uncheck the Auto Reboot option.
2. When Odin finishes the flashing procedure; use the suitable key combination to boot into TWRP Recovery Mode.
3. From the TWRP menu; boot into system.

Tip : In some cases, if a problem occurs try to flash an older version of TWRP

From [TWRP](https://twrp.me/samsung/samsunggalaxynote3neo.html)

> Note many devices will replace your custom recovery automatically during first boot. To prevent this, use your preferred search engine to find the proper key combo to enter recovery. After typing fastboot reboot, hold the key combo and boot to TWRP. Once TWRP is booted, TWRP will patch the stock ROM to prevent the stock ROM from replacing TWRP. If you don't follow this step, you will have to repeat the install.

Hope this solution help others too.

Comment: Tip, if it malfunctions at times, try using older versions of TWRP

Comment: Added all comments on the answer:)

Comment: +1. Thanks  and hope to see more contributions from you